# how can I use the fileupload helper when it is loaded in another page using the load jquery method?

Tags: file-upload, html-helper, asp.net-webpages

I have the following problem, one page load in one of his div using the Load method from Jquery Ajax another page that use the FileUpload Asp.net Helper. Alone that page Works fine, but inside this div the upload button apparently calls the hosting page, not the page that original has the helper.
In consecuence, How can correctly use the helper loaded from another page?
In a scheme I think that this is happening:

[image]

And I want this to happen, but don't know how to do it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upload button submits the form. It will be submitted to whatever location is specified in the `action` attribute of the form. Therefore you should set the `action` attribute value to the page that you want the form to post to.

This will be easier to manage if you set `includeFormTag` to false. It is true by default:

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml(
    initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
    allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
    includeFormTag: false,
    uploadText: "Upload",
    name: "Upload1"
)
```

You will then need to provide your own form tag. Make sure you include the correct `enctype` for managing file uploads:

```
<form action="somePage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
```